# FusionCharts Gauges have same code but different outputs

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

For a project i'm creating a dashboard and i would like 3 gauges on the platform. Those gauges are placed in a bootstrap card with a column value of 4. In the dashboard there are 3 cards next to eachother.

I'm able to render the gauges for every card and every gauge has the same properties but outputs to a different diff and with a different value for the gauge dial.

In the screenshot you can see the issue:
[image]

Every Gauge has a data set:

```
const performanceChart = {
    chart: {
        caption: "Gauge 3",
        lowerlimit: "0",
        upperlimit: "100",
        showvalue: "1",
        numbersuffix: "%",
        theme: "fusion",
        showtooltip: "0"
    },
    colorrange: {
        color: [
            {
                minvalue: "0",
                maxvalue: "50",
                code: "#F2726F"
            },
            {
                minvalue: "50",
                maxvalue: "75",
                code: "#FFC533"
            },
            {
                minvalue: "75",
                maxvalue: "100",
                code: "#62B58F"
            }
        ]
    },
    dials: {
        dial: [
            {
                value: "{{$performance}}"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

And a function to render it:

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
            var performance = new FusionCharts({
                type: "angulargauge",
                renderAt: "performance-container",
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                dataFormat: "json",
                dataSource: performanceChart,
            }).render();
        });
```

All the functions are the same but the datasource and the renderAt: are different.

How does this problem occur? And how can i solve the issue where every added gauge grows.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating the issue and could not find any erroneous behavior in the gauge `width` or gauge dial `value` if the same code is provided for the different gauges.

Please refer to this fiddle to find my way of replicating the behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/omk32qwu/

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var performance = new FusionCharts({
      type: "angulargauge",
      renderAt: `container${i}`,
      width: "100%",
      dataFormat: "json",
      dataSource: performanceChart,
    }).render();
  }
```

Please replicate the behavior where you are getting the different dial values for the same dial value provided in the code and share with me.

Hope this would help.

Comment: I found out that for some reason the height and width didnt actually work for the gauges unless i forced the height and width on the actuall container

Comment: @Collin It should not be the case. Can you please share a fiddle replicating the issue you're facing?